# Why does casting a large double to a long sometimes return a positive and other times return a negative value in C?

Tags: objective-c, c, casting, double, long-integer

I put this into an iOS test case and ran it in the (32 bit iPad) simulator:

```
double whu = 3166323616091.220215;
NSLog(@"Double: %f", whu);
NSLog(@"Long:   %ld", (long)whu);
NSLog(@"Double: %f", 3166323616091.220215);
NSLog(@"Long:   %ld", (long)3166323616091.220215);
```

The output is:

```
2014-04-23 13:40:50.904 xctest[53336:303] Double: 3166323616091.220215
2014-04-23 13:40:50.905 xctest[53336:303] Long:   -2147483648
2014-04-23 13:40:50.906 xctest[53336:303] Double: 3166323616091.220215
2014-04-23 13:40:50.907 xctest[53336:303] Long:   2147483647
```

I get why it truncates the big double value to the max value for long (32bit). But why does casting the *variable* return the negative value when casting the *literal* returns a positive value? In fact, I don't understand why the negative is returned at all. Am I missing something having to do with precision, perhaps?

Comment: As far as C is concerned, one is undefined behaviour (signed integer overflow), the other is implementation-defined (conversion-to-signed).

Comment: The variable cast is done by the runtime system and the literal is done by the compiler. There isn't a "good" answer for either.  One gave you 0x7FFFFFFF and the other gave you 0x80000000.

Comment: Of course! I've updated my code to the equivalent of `(long)MIN(whu, LONG_MAX)` to fix my issue. I guess that's the correct way to deal with it?

Comment: @theory `(long)MAX(MIN(whu, LONG_MAX), LONG_MIN)` to catch both ends.  Suggest instead calling your own `double LongTODouble(long)` and encapsulating this conversion.

Comment: chux: Yep, already doing that. Thanks. @brad-budlong: Want to add an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting a variable will result in the runtime code doing the conversion and the resulting overflow is producing the max negative number (0x80000000 an undefined result, but what this runtime is doing).  Casting the constant will cause the compiler to convert the number and it does convert to the maximum positive number (0x7FFFFFFF).